# Auto-Layout UIScrollView and an animated UIView

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode5, autolayout

Currently having an issue with using auto-layout and UIScrollView.  The issue is when I scroll down on the scroll view, a previous UIView (that should be free roaming, and is animated to various positions) gets set back to its initial location where it is located in Storyboard.

What's the best way to make my single UIView not follow the behavior of auto-layout and let it do whatever it wants to do?

Comment: Have you tried adding that `UIView` programmatically?

Comment: That seems to resolve the issue.  Is there no way to achieve the same affect with a UIView in a Storyboard by chance?  Thanks for the answer @friedegg-bacon-sandwich

Comment: Not that I know of to be honest. Normally when working with animation, I have to add every single view by code. Glad to help anyway!